# How to include long text in a table with latex?

Tags: latex, tabular

I'm using a table and I set the size of the columns to be 2.5cm. 
However, if I add a long line, the size of the column changes its value.

```
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm} l p{2cm} l p{2cm} l p{2cm} l p{2cm} l p{2cm} l p{2cm} l p{2cm}}
 & \textbf{Fair Trade} & \textbf{SAN/RA} & \textbf{GlobalGAP} & \textbf{Unilever Sustainable Agriculture Code}
& \textbf{Bio Suisse} & \textbf{Naturland} & \textbf{EU Bio} \\ \hline

\textbf{Key features} & \textbf{Established in}& 1997 &1987 & 1997 &6 &7 &8\\ \hline

\textbf{Sector scope} &this is a very long line that needs to be cut &3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `\parbox`:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm} l p{2cm} l p{2cm} l p{2cm} l p{2cm} l p{2cm} l p{2cm} l p{2cm}}
 & \textbf{Fair Trade} & \textbf{SAN/RA} & \textbf{GlobalGAP} & \textbf{Unilever Sustainable Agriculture Code}
& \textbf{Bio Suisse} & \textbf{Naturland} & \textbf{EU Bio} \\ \hline

\textbf{Key features} & \textbf{Established in}& 1997 &1987 & 1997 &6 &7 &8\\ \hline

\textbf{Sector scope} & \parbox{2cm}{this is a very long line that needs to be cut} &3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: With that I need to add \parbox{2cm} every time I have a long text to split. Is there any way to do it for all cells in the table?